# Generate a list based on the index of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
hash_table = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to change this to:

```
result = [[0, 0], [1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

How to generate:

```
array: [1,    0,    1,    1,    1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1,    1]

map:    0    0.5   1.0   1.5   2.0   2.5   3.0   3.5   4.0   4.5   5.0
# start to end, generate the result like `[int(start), int(end)]`
combine them:[[0, 0], [1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

`0` and `1` wouldn't appear in pairs. So the numbers in result must be an integer.

What I have tried:

```
hash_table = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
output = [[]]
for pre, next_ in zip(hash_table, hash_table[1:]):
    output[-1].append(pre)
    if {next_, pre} == {0, 1}:
        output.append([])
output[-1].append(hash_table[-1])
# the output is [[1], [0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
start = index = 0
result = []
while index < len(output):
    # output[index]
    if output[0] != 0:
        res.append([start, math.ceil(len(output[index]))])
        # I don't know how to handle the list "output".
        # I couldn't know it. My mind has gone blank
    start += len(output[index])/2
```

Any good ideas? I thought I made it too complicated.

Comment: What exactly is your question about the code you have shown?

Comment: I don't get how the desired result is derived from the input.  I get that `0, 0` gives the start and end of a run of 1s, but what does `1, 2` correspond to?

Comment: @Samwise I guess the result is supposed to be the list of pairs of start and end indices floor-divided by 2 for each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the 0s and 1s:

```py
import itertools

hash_table = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

result = []
cur_ind = 0

for (val, vals) in itertools.groupby(hash_table):
    vals = list(vals) # itertools doesn't make it a list by default
    old_ind = cur_ind
    cur_ind += len(vals)
    if val == 0:
        continue
    result.append([old_ind // 2, (cur_ind - 1) // 2])

print(result)
```

Essentially, `itertools.groupby` will give an iterator of `[(1, [1]), (0, [0]), (1, [1, 1, 1]), (0, [0, 0, 0]), (1, [1, 1, 1])]` (more or less). We can iterate through this iterator and keep track if the index we're on by adding the length of the sublist to the current index. If the value is 1, then we have a run of ones so we append it to the results. The `old_ind // 2` is integer division and is equivalent to `int(old_ind / 2)`.

Comment: A little hard to understand for me.But it is a very good answer.I will try to understand this.Thanks.Could you explain it?

Comment: @KevinMayo Sure, I've edited a bit of an explanation in. Let me know if you're still confused on anything.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, kind stranger <3

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupby from itertools library:

```
import itertools
hash_table = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
s = "".join(map(str, hash_table)) # s = "10111000111"
gs = [(i, list(g)) for i, g in itertools.groupby(s)]

idx, result = 0, []
for i, g in gs: # i can be '1' or '0' (i.e, if the group consist in 1's or 0's)
    if i == '1':
        result.append([idx/2, (idx + len(g) - 1)/2])
    idx += len(g)
return result
```